# BizTalk 2010 Configuration Failure

Tags: configuration, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I've two 64-bit Windows Server 2008 R2 machines. On one of the machines BizTalk Server 2010 Standard Edition is installed & on the other SQL Server 2008 R2 is installed.

When I use the 'BizTalk Server Configuration' on the BizTalk machine to create the necessary databases on the SQL Server machine, just the 'SSODB' gets created & then the configuration fails due to below errors

> Failed to create the SQL database 'SSODB' on SQL Server 'SQLServerName' (with SSO Administrator account 'SSO Administrators').
>
> (0xC0002A21) An error occurred while attempting to access the SSO database.
>
> Could not find the account name 'SSO Administrators' on computer 'SQLServerName'. Configuration can proceed, but it might fail.
>
> (0x800706BA) The RPC server is unavailable.

A few sites suggested to register both the 32-bit & 64-bit SSOSQL.dll using the regasm command to resolve this issue & I did the same. But, the issue still persists.

What is a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create "Domain user accounts/user groups" before configuring and use those instead of the local user accounts/user groups. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577661(v=BTS.70).aspx)
2. Add the domain user account as sys-admin on the Sql server.

Most likely the above 2 steps will help you resolve this issue.